# How to show in a label first 100 even numbers using While and Do While ? c#

Tags: c#, while-loop, numbers

Actually i have a button to display the first 100 even numbers using For

```
    int a = 100;
        int res = 0;
        int i;
        string npares = "";
        for (i = 0; i <= a; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                res = res + i;
                if (i < a)
                    npares += i + ",";
                else
                    npares += i;
            }


        }
        LBLstatus.MaximumSize = new Size(200, 0);
        LBLstatus.Text = npares;
```

But i need to make the same with more two buttons using While and Do While , how i can make this ?

EDIT >>>>>>

Using while i got this way :

```
int a = 100;
        int i = 0;
        string npares = "";
        int res = 0;

        while (i <= a)
        {
            i++;
            if

                (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                res = res + i;
                if (i < a)
                    npares += i + ",";
                else
                    npares += i;
            }
            LBLstatus.Text = npares;
```

Comment: Pretty much the same way mate. Google how while and do while loops work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This answer shows the relationship between constructs, but does not otherwise attempt to provide a solution.)

---

The construct

```
for (init;cond;post)
{
    body;
}
```

can be generally rewritten as / considered equivalent to

```
init;
while (cond) {
    body;
    post;
}
```

On the other hand a do-while has no analogous simple `for` form, because it delays evaluation of `cond` until after the body has been executed once, but it can be written as

```
for (init;;post) {
    body;
    if (!cond) break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm studying these methods today and was easy, but when I needed to perform the repetition of even numbers did not know where to start and the method that is thought to was what I found on google but I could not just switch to the other methods , i need to study and rewrite the code for these methods

Answer (score -2):

### Using `Take`

```
List<int> ints;

List<int> positiveInts = ints.Where(i => i % 2 == 0).Take(100).ToList();
```

### Using `Aggregate`

```
List<int> ints;

string positiveInts = ints.Where(i => i % 2 == 0).Take(100).Select(i => i.ToString()).Aggregate((a,b) => b += String.IsNullOrEmpty(b) ? a : "," + a);
```

Comment: -1 Did you read his question or just the code? He needs to repeat the functionality of the for loop, but using while loops and do while loops instead.

Comment: Neither of your solutions use loops.  While they *do* include the even numbers between 0 and 100, they are completely unrelated to the question.

Comment: They don't even compile, as written.

Comment: It may be simpler but my teacher wants me to use these methods unfortunately

Comment: @Andrew He's a beginner that's trying to learn about loops. Showing him a lambda function with no explanation of how it works isn't helpful.